# Update Angular ion-view in another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

Im new here on stackoverflow and new to AngularJS.

Im trying to build a Ionic app, and here is my problem.

I would like to change the date in one template(date.html), using Controller: DateCtrl, and change the GEO location in another template(geo.html), using Controller: GEOCtrl.

And when I change the date and the geo location, I would like my list in a third template(sun.html) to update, using Controller: SunCtrl.

I can see the changes in date template and GEO template just fine, but I can not figure out how to update my liste in my sun.html template, after changes in date and geo location templates.

I've been trying to use $scope.$watch in the SunListCtrl Controller, and set $scope.$apply in the GEOCtrl and the DateCtrl. But not with any luck.

But how can I get my list in the sun.html template to update, each time and change happens in the date or GEO location?

sun.html template:

```
<ion-view view-title="Sun list">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="sun in sunList.sunlist">
                {{sun.title}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

geo.html:

```
Latitude: {{geo.latitude}}<br />
Longitude: {{geo.longitude}}<br />
City: {{geo.city}}<br />
Date: {{date.dato}}<br />

<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-radio" ng-repeat="area in areas">
        <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="geo.city" value="{{area.city}}" ng-change="change({{area.id}})" >
        <div class="item-content">
            {{area.city}}
        </div>
        <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

date.html

```
Latitude: {{geo.latitude}}<br />
Longitude: {{geo.longitude}}<br />
City: {{geo.city}}<br />
Date: {{date.dato}}<br />
<br />
<h3>Select date:</h3>
<input type="text" ng-model="date.dato" />

<label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Date</span>
    <input type="date"  ng-model="date.dato">
</label>
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

    .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

    })

    .factory('ActiveDate', function(){
        var date = this;
        date.dato = new Date();
        return this;
    })

    .factory('Geo', function(){
        var Geo = this;
        Geo.latitude = "55.67610";
        Geo.longitude = "12.56834";
        Geo.city = "Copenhagen";
        return this;
    })

    .factory('SunList', function(ActiveDate, Geo){
        // I need GEO location and date to calculate the sunrise
        // I use this: https://github.com/mourner/suncalc
        var geoTime = SunCalc.getTimes(ActiveDate.dato, Geo.latitude, Geo.longitude);

        var sunList = this;
        sunList.sunlist = [];

        // I the original code I do some more - but this is the basic stuff.
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            sunList.sunlist.push({
                title: 'Hour #' + i
            });
        }
        return this;
    })

    .controller('SunListCtrl', function ($scope, ActiveDate, Geo, SunList) {
        $scope.sunList = SunList;
    })

    .controller('DateCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, ActiveDate, Geo) {
        $scope.date = ActiveDate;
        $scope.geo = Geo;
    })

    .controller('GEOCtrl', function ($scope, ActiveDate, Geo) {
        $scope.date = ActiveDate;
        $scope.geo = Geo;
        $scope.change = function (id) {
            $scope.geo.city = $scope.areas[id].city;
            Geo.latitude = $scope.areas[id].latitude;
            Geo.longitude = $scope.areas[id].longitude;
        };
        $scope.areas =
            [
                {id: 0, city: "Copenhagen", latitude: "55.67610", longitude: "12.56834"},
                {id: 1, city: "New York", latitude: "40.71278", longitude: "-74.00594"},
                {id: 2, city: "Bangkok", latitude: "13.75633", longitude: "100.50177"}
            ];
    });
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general in AngularJS if you want to communicate between controllers you should use a service.

Create a service and have each of your controllers (geo and date) set values in the service that would then control the value it returns to the SunListCtrl that you use in the ng-repeat.

I've posted a full demo of two controllers talking to a service which is then used to get list data for a third controller here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKqVqV?p=preview

The service looks like this:

```
app.service('List', function($rootScope, $log) {
  service = {}; // the service object we'll return

  var dateValue = 'date';
  var geoValue = 'geo';
  var theList = [];

  service.setGeo = function(data) {
    geoValue = data;
    updateList();
  }

  service.setDate = function(data) {
    dateValue = data;
    updateList();
  }

  function updateList() {
    theList = [dateValue, geoValue];
    $rootScope.$broadcast('updatedList');  // broadcasts the update to listeners 
  }

  service.getList = function() {
    return theList;
  }

  return service;
});
```

Basically updates to the date or geo controllers are passed to the service with List.setGeo(data) and List.setDate(data) calls.  Those calls update local service variables and then rebuild the list used by the SunList controller.  The service also broadcasts an update telling that controller that the list has updated.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, can you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I have one in the works. I just didn't get it done before having to run out for a doctor appointment.

Comment: OK, there's your example included in the answer now.

Comment: Super - I will look in to it later to day :-)

Comment: Sorry for not comming back.
Thank you very much - it works now :-)

Comment: @PeterLauge If the answer worked for you, please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to the voting score (which is currently 0).

Comment: Ahhh - that's how I do it. Thanks :-)